faces after bolean modifier separated
I have drawn a plane and cut off some part via the bolean modifier. This worked.
Now, when I switch to edit mode, I see two separated faces:

How can I avoid this!
Update: since @JohnEason helped already I have some more input for John (or others):


I created the primary plane and bleved the corners
I then created a second plane which has the form I want to cut out from the primary.
I tried modifier bolean again, but did not work. I think, the forms must be meshes to get this working - but I am not sure.



I would like to attach my file her, but did not find howto!

You can't! Holes in Blender have to have at least two edges connecting them to surrounding geometry which means that you will have two faces in this case.

@JohnEason Is there any way to cut off some part of a plane in a different way. Because next step I would like to bevel the outer corners which seems not to work if there are two separate faces.

You can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. Assuming that you just want to bevel the corners, is there any reason why you can't bevel them _before_using the boolean modifier? - I don't really see why you need to boolean it in any case if it's just a simple plane. Select the face, use 'I' to inset  and then 'X' to delete the centre face.

I have now started different. draw plane, conv to mesh, bevel corners. Now I wil try to cut out the part I don't need. Probably this is a better way!

@JohnEason aah - yes - this I will give it a try - thanks

so far not completely successfull, since the form I want to delete (or cut out) from the plane is not exactly the same shape. I want to construct a second plane with the specific form and then cut out this from the origin one. If you could give me some help on that please. see update in topic!

As I said in a comment above we'll need to see your Blend file and I gave you the instructions there to share it via https://blend-exchange.com/!  I'm not sure why you're talking about 'converting to mesh'? I'f you added a Plane object, that already is a mesh!

this should be the file: 

I've added that link into your question as I asked you to do. I suggest you start another question rather than extending the comments here!
